# Learn kernel module, module.ko cause module is already loaded?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am learning kernel module now, so I setup a Ubuntu 16.04 with `kernel 4.4.0-28-generic` in a virtual machine.

I installed this packages

```
# dpkg -l | grep linux
ii  console-setup-linux                  1.108ubuntu15                            all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                    2.4-3build2                              amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-base                           4.0ubuntu1                               all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                       1.157.2                                  all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                        4.4.0.28.30                              amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-28               4.4.0-28.47                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic       4.4.0-28.47                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                4.4.0.28.30                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic         4.4.0-28.47                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic   4.4.0-28.47                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                  4.4.0.28.30                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                 4.4.0-28.47                              amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-sound-base                     1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                     all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  linux-source                         4.4.0.28.30                              all          Linux kernel source with Ubuntu patches
ii  linux-source-4.4.0                   4.4.0-28.47                              all          Linux kernel source for version 4.4.0 with Ubuntu patches
ii  util-linux                           2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1                        amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

I already decompresses the kernel source package `/usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0.tar.bz2` to `/home/test/WorkSpace/Kernel/linux-source-4.4.0`.

My system uname is

```
# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-ldm 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I write a test module **hello.c**

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init (void) {
        printk (KERN_ALERT "Hello, World\n");
        return 0;
}

static void hello_exit (void) {
        printk (KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init (hello_init);
module_exit (hello_exit);
```

**Makefile**

```
obj-m += module.o

module-objs := hello.o

all:
        make modules M=`pwd` -C /home/test/WorkSpace/Kernel/linux-source-4.4.0

clean:
        make modules clean M=`pwd` -C /home/test/WorkSpace/Kernel/linux-source-4.4.0
```

But something confused me. I make my module and try to `insmod`, and I got an error

```
# sudo insmod module.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module module.ko: Invalid module format
```

What cause this error?

Did I use wrong version of kernel source?

---

for osgx

There is no additional line in output of **dmesg** after I try to **insmod**. The modinfo shows this

```
# modinfo module.ko
filename:       /home/test/WorkSpace/LDM/hello/module.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
depends:
vermagic:       4.4.13 SMP mod_unload
```

I try to change the source path in the Makefile, remake it, and I get the new .ko

The modinfo of the new .ko is

```
# modinfo module.ko
filename:       /home/joshua/WorkSpace/LDM/hello/module.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
srcversion:     82C361DBCB1C9BB5CA1DB07
depends:
vermagic:       4.4.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

But the problem still there, and the **dmesg** log looks like this

```
[   28.540701] module: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   28.540879] module: module is already loaded
```

---

It looks like there is a module named `module` already in the system, so I try to change the target name in the **Makefile** to `hello.o`, make the new target name as `hello.ko`, after that the module works.

But when I ran `lsmod | grep module`, there is no module named `module`?

Comment: Joshua, do you have any additional lines in output of `dmesg` command after such insmod? What is output of `modinfo` on your module? Try to build using `make module M=\`pwd\` -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` - this is build dir for your current kernel with correct config, not just 4.4.0 downloaded from kernel.org (they are different, you should built exactly for your kernel; in ubuntu there is dkms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support to recompile module on kernel update).

Comment: @osgx I updated the question for the new info formatting.

Comment: Don't call it module.ko then, call it something else!

Comment: You don't need the kernel source. You can just install the linux-headers-_flavor_ package that matches your running kernel. That would be `linux-headers-generic` in your case. Then you can do ```make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules``` to build against the running kernel.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the module is loaded statically.

Then it won't show under `lsmod`, but you can still see it with:

```
ls /sys/module
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364956/how-can-insmod-fail-with-kernel-module-is-already-loaded-even-is-lsmod-does-not